# Handle 4XX http codes with resources / interceptors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I need a solution for handling HTTP `4XX` status codes. I used to have an error interceptor like this

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .factory('errorInterceptor', function (....) {

         return {
             responseError: function (response) {
                 if (response.status === '404') {
                     $rootScope.error = response; 
                 } else if (....) {...}

                 return $q.reject(response);
             }
         };
    };
});
```

And in the HTML the error is shown like this

```
<body message="error"> ....
```

When the error is shown, the user has to login again (or something else): it stops the flow of the application.

But I have many resources and for some it is OK to show this error message, but others should handle the error themselves in the error callback

```
taks.$update(function(taks) { /* succes */ }, function (response) { /* error */});
```

What would be the best strategy/solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you possibly inject a function into the `errorInterceptor`, and then depending on where you call it from you can pass in different functions that do different things?  If it needs to show an error message, don't pass a function then check for undefined and show an error message.

Comment: You mean a factory ? I can of course define some rules in the resource which are set in a factory when the resource is used. Then I inject this factory in the errorInterceptor which uses these rules to determine what to do. Is this what you mean (more or less) ?

Comment: I mean passing a literal function to the `errorInterceptor`, like so:  `.factory('errorInterceptor', function( errorMessageFunc, .... ) {`.  Then, later if there is an error you can just say `errorMessageFunc()` and it will do whatever you need it to do if you find that there is a 404 or something else.  I'm just spitballing here, this may not be the best and most "angular" way to solve the problem.